# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have this web.xml file

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml /WEB-INF/core-spring-beans.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and applicationContext that include the Bean

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>


    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>


  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="pull_DS" resource-ref="true"/>

  <bean id="sqlMapClient"
        class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean"
        p:configLocation="classpath:pull/DBUtils/sqlMapConfig.xml"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

  <bean id="daoBase" abstract="true"
        p:sqlMapClient-ref="sqlMapClient"/>

  <bean id="Photo"
        class="pull.DBUtils.PopPhotoImpl"
        parent="daoBase"/>

  <bean id="Trunkcate"
        class="pull.DBUtils.TrunkcateCifSrcImpl"
        parent="daoBase"/>

    <bean id="applicationContextProvder"class="pull.DBUtils.ApplicationContextProvider"/>     
</beans>
```

and the ApplicationContextProvider.java for ApplicationContext

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

AND so I defined a method returnCleanUp in TrunkcateCifSrcImpl Bean as

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


public class TrunkcateCifSrcImpl extends iBatisTemplate implements TrunkcateCifSrc{


public int retTrunkcateReady() {
     return super.trunkcateReady("CifSrc_Trunkcate.cleanUp");
}

public static int returnCleanUp() {
    TrunkcateCifSrcImpl trunkcate = null;
    int result;
    try {
        ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext();
        trunkcate = (TrunkcateCifSrcImpl) ctx.getBean("Trunkcate");
        result = trunkcate.retTrunkcateReady();
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException noBeanE) {
        throw noBeanE;
    } catch (BeansException beanE) {
        throw beanE;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

The iBatisTemplate class to return a value of map "trunkcateReady" (value returns back from iBatis function called from database)

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport;

import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapExecutor;

public class iBatisTemplate extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport {

    public int trunkcateReady(final String id) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(1);
        getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject(id, map);
        return map.get("trunkcateReady");
    }

  }
```

but now once in awhile if i call this method from Trunkcate bean I would receive that exceptionm IllegalStateException, does anyone know what can I do to fix this??

```
do{
    cleanUp = TrunkcateCifSrcImpl.returnCleanUp();
    if(cleanUp==1)
    {       
        logger.debug("Going to sleep........");
        Thread.sleep(65000);
    }
}while(cleanUp!=0);
```

Stack trace exception I got, this usually happens the first time it go through the loop then after Thread.sleep(65000), it will go back in normally

```
2014-02-14 12:23:45,646 GMT-0800 [managedServer=weeManagedServer-1]pull.quartzScheduler.PullingPDRTask - Pull failed....
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at pull.DBUtils.TrunkcateCifSrcImpl.returnCleanUp(TrunkcateCifSrcImpl.java:21)
    at pull.quartzScheduler.PullingPDRTask.excute(PullingPDRTask.java:257)
    at pull.quartzScheduler.SchedulerService.executePullingPDRTask(SchedulerService.java:31)
    at pull.quartzScheduler.PullStatefulJob.executeInternal(PullStatefulJob.java:42)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Thanks! any input would be helpful. I deploy my app on weblogic server 1036jdk1.7. Using spring 3.1.1. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Also, the truncateDAO. Is it mentioned as a dependency for your TruncateCifSrcImpl class? It doesnt show that way in the xml config

Comment: Including my stacktrace where it failed. It failed when it tries to getBean "Trunkcate". This whole application also using Quartz to scheduling and wakes up every 30mins, "returnCleanUp" is a part of the "executePullingPDRTask". As long as cleanUp return still!=0, "returnCleanUp" will be kept calling. Ps: not sure if it helps, I ony set quartz thread =1 to reduce multiple threading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Issue when i worked on Spring MVC using Tomcat 6 but i had by mistake declared multiple bean classes with the same name , check your classes once for ambiguity   . Please post the complete stack trace .

Just In case if it helps this was my mistake so i got that error .
 Annotation-specified bean name 'countryServiceImpl' for bean class [com.ssrv.fms.service.contact.impl.CountryServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.ssrv.fms.service.admin.impl.CountryServiceImpl]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the target folder of your project, and check if the configuration files are there.

And I think you should tell more details of the `errorInfo`, it will be helpful.

I've met the same problem you have. But I had more detail error information under the

```
BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

It says

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

So I check the target folder of the project, the "spring" folder is missing, which all of my configuration files in it. Although I don't know why it's not in there.

So I delete the target folder of the project, and rebuild it. And problem's solved. The 'spring' folder appeared.

Before and after:

[image: before]
[image: after]